# Integrate js with button on uiComponent xml

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, adminhtml, custom

I have the following custom form in my admin html and I have tried to insert a javascript function on my custom button click but the page being in a infinity loading loop.

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/addfat_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">    
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">addfat_form.addfat_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">addfat_form.addfat_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Nova fatura</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">addfat_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="btn_load_client" xsi:type="string">PereiraTech\Faturamento\Block\Adminhtml\Buttons\Edit\Button\CustomButton</item>
        </item>        
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="addfat_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PereiraTech\Faturamento\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">addfat_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">fat_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">fat_id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="title">        
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Nova fatura</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="fat_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID da fatura</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">fat_id</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>        
        <field name="cliente_mail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email do cliente</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_id</item>                    
                </item>              
            </argument>                        
        </field>             
        <field name="cliente">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cliente</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">cliente</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="cliente_cpf_cnpj">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CPF/CNPJ</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">cliente_cpf_cnpj</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="vendas_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Compras</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">vendas_id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">PereiraTech\Faturamento\Model\DataProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="data_inicio">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">De</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data_inicio</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>                        
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="data_fim">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Até</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data_fim</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>                        
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="subtotal">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal:</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">subtotal</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>        
        <field name="desconto">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Desconto</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">desconto</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="total">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Total</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">total</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="pago">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pago</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fatura</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">pago</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>                    
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="sync" sortOrder="40" formElement="button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Sync</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">center</item>   
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">PereiraTech_Faturamento/js/form/element/options</item>                 
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>      
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/options.js

```
define([        
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({


        onClick: function(){
            console.log('Worked');


            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

A point is that the button doesn't show up too.

The page at infinity loop
[image: loading]

**[UPDATE]** First, that was a mistake at the XML, the path for the JS file was wrong, solved. Second, I've updated my JS code following `magefms` code, but the `require` was giving another error, so I've roll back to `define`. I looked at the console and saw a new error that sounds as progress.

> [ERROR] Failed to load the "PereiraTech_Faturamento/js/form/element/options" component

Now the page loads but the component still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The path for the JS file in the XML was wrong, instead of the full patch `PereiraTech_Faturamento/view/adminhtml/web/js...` need to replace just for `PereiraTech_Faturamento/js...`
- In the JS file, change `'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select'` to `'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button'`
- And finally `onClick` to `action`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `require` instead

```
require([    
 'jquery', 
 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        $(document).on("click", function(){
            console.log('Worked');

            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = data_fim');
            field1.hide();

            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

UPDATE: Format your element options component path like this:

```
PereiraTech_Faturamento/js/form/element/options
```

no need for full path with `view/adminhtml/web/js....`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't worked.

Comment: @MuriloPereira updated answer please check

Comment: updated question, please check. And the $(documento).on was giving error, "Unexpected Token"

Comment: my mistake @MuriloPereira it was the js

Comment: I'm still facing the problem [ERROR] Failed to load the "PereiraTech_Faturamento/js/form/element/options" component